# Apostrophes in plurals

Tags: grammatical-number, apostrophe, vowels

I have always thought plurals in English is always word + s (except for irregular plurals). In my language we use apostrophes when a word ends in a vowel. I have been correcting my friends who write `line's` instead of `lines`.

About a week ago I went to the UK. I noticed advertising boards with phrases that do use apostrophes in plurals. No, this was not like `The cat's leaping` as in `The cat is leaping` but something along the lines of `We sell car's`.

I am very confused now, can anyone explain this to me please?

Comment: You're right, the advertising boards are wrong. People who write signs are notorious for misusing apostrophes: people have called this the "[grocer's apostrophe](http://walkinthewords.blogspot.com/2009/05/grocers-apostrophe.html)" or "greengrocer's apostrophe."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `line's` means belonging to the line, whereas `lines` means multiple instances of a line.

So the sentence "We sells car's" does not make sense because you aren't identifying what the part of the car you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Apostrophes are only used for plurals when ambiguities might arise in their absence.  For instance the plural of the capital letter *A* is A's to avoid confusion with the word *As*.

You may clear up your confusion by ignoring punctuation advice from advertising boards.